# Como obtener headers con python

Tags: python, aws, lambda

Buen día.
De que manera es posible obtener los header de la petición de un API.
Esto lo intento realizar desde lambdas con python en AWS. Basicamente requiero capturar los header del 'Authorization: Basic, decodificarlo y compararlo con los datos de una base de datos, y si estos son correctos entonces retornar el resultado de la petición.
Favor de tener en cuenta que soy totalmente nuevo con python.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a las cabeceras debes inspeccionar el objeto `event` que recibes como parámetro de entrada:

```
def handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
```

Aunque no es la mejor forma de programar una lambda basada en http.

Si requieres autorización en una lambda, lo suyo sería emplear FastAPI o un API Gateway.

Si usas AWS API Gateway puedes programar una lambda autorizadora. Esto es una lambda cuya única misión es comprobar que el token o las credenciales son correctas y con ello permitir o denegar la ejecución de la lambda principal.

Si optas por usar FastAPI puedes configurar la autorización fuera de la función propia del endpoint, lo que te ayuda igualmente a aislar las diferentes responsabilidades. Más información sobre fastapi [aquí](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/first-steps/)